# Display the multiple selected values with select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have one array `@name = ["D2", "D3"]`, so how to set this in `select_tag` as selected options.

i am trying with this, but not displaying that

```
<%= select_tag "add", options_for_select(["D1","D2","D3","D4"],{
@name.each do |id| :selected =>"#{id}" } ), {:multiple => true}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript or jQuery? Please don't spray-tag. Use only the relevant tags to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
<%= select_tag "add", options_for_select(["D1","D2","D3","D4"], :selected =>["D1","D4"]) , :multiple => true %>
```

Unless your `name.id` gives you a "D1", you might want to change your approach. What field in `name` corresponds to "D1"?

Answer (score 2):

What about  that :

`<%= select_tag "add", options_for_select(["D1","D2","D3","D4"],@name), {:multiple => true} %>`

Comment: @user2342350, do note that all these options will not have any `value` [which is usually not wanted]